# calendar with sql

Tags: php, mysql

PHP+SQL question:

I have table for assignments
one of the field is "progTargetDate" -> linux time (eg: 1348185600 )
I also built calender and I want to check if I have any assignment for each day I print

so - I wrote the query that bring me all the assignment for the current month

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ass.id, ass.title, ass.des, ass.progTargetDate 
                        FROM pro_assignments AS ass, pro_progs2assignments AS pr 
                        WHERE   (ass.progTargetDate >= $ChoosenMonth_start) AND
                                (ass.progTargetDate <= $ChoosenMonth_end) 
                        ORDER BY ass.progTargetDate ASC
                        ");
```

(I delete part of the SQL query))

and I have the loop that build the calendar cell

```
for ($i = 1 ; $i <= $total_days_in_month ; $i++)
{
}
```

$i = each day in the month

I tried to build IF condition without success
I want to check for each day if it found inside the array (that I got from the first query)

(this code goes inside the FOR loop:)

```
echo "<td>$i"; 
        while($index = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
        {
                $progTargetDate = $index['progTargetDate'];
                if ((mktime(0, 0, 0, date($ChoosenMonth)  , $i, date($ChoosenYear)) == $progTargetDate))
                    echo "<p>found</p>";
                else
                    echo "<p>not</p>";

        }

echo "</td>";
```

What do I do wrong?

---

for 31 days I should have 31 cell with "found" or "not" in each one. but for some reason only in the first cell I see this result

Comment: What is the error message you get? What is the problem?

Comment: Try to add `var_dump($index);` to your loop and see what you got...

Comment: for 31 days I should have 31 cell with "found" or "not" in each one. but for some reason only in the first cell I see this result